# Why do we need "a:link"? Why not just "a"?

Tags: html, css

It seems the following variants produce identical results:

```
/* 1 */
a, a:visited, a:active { color: black; }
a:hover { color: red; }

/* 2 */
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active { color: black; }
a:hover { color: red; }

/* 3 */
a:link, a:visited, a:active { color: black; }
a:hover { color: red; }
```

Most guidance on the web uses 2 or 3. Why not go for the simplest variant which is 1? I cannot find a good reason to ever apply `:link` if all you need is one style for normal links and one for hover.

Is it best-practice to not use `:link`? Why or why not?

**I don't care whether the link is visited or not.** Both receive the same style. I only care about hover or not hover. This question is not about what the variants do - all do the same thing. It is about what the *best* variant is. Is one of the variants faulty? Which one is best-practice?

Comment: I thought "best practice" questions weren't what SO was here for? Are you saying would `a, a:link` *ever, ever* produce results different from just `a` in the limited use case you suggest? It seems as if you're asking if a micro-optimization is worth worrying about.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't worry about perf, but about productivity. The :link thing also gave me a little trouble when overriding just the non-hover style on some element.

Comment: And I would say that `a:link, a:visited, a:active` makes more sense if you're strictly targeting *actual* links. I use `<a>` (*not* `<a[href]>`) all the time, not a link.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PmsP8/1/ (edited) Note the addition of the `a:link` to `:hover` as well, and try clicking on the last `No HREF` element.

Comment: You are basically asking for opinions, and in an abstract context at that. For usability and accessibility, visited and unvisited links should look different, and then the question does not arise.

Comment: If this question had been posted by someone with little reputation, it would have been closed. *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."*

Comment: @TheApptracker I come to think you're right. The question derailed pretty badly. On the other hand, most misunderstandings *are* addressed in the question - it just appears to be to convoluted to be understood. Not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Because not every `a` is a link.

```
<a name="table_of_contents">Table of Contents</a>
```

isn't a link, it's an anchor that can be linked to with `<a href="#table_of_contents">`.

`a` will match it, `a:link` won't.

Comment: (But now we have linkable IDs, so you don’t have to jump through the `a:link, a:visited` hoop anymore.)

Comment: @hobbs, This doesn't explain why `a:active` was invented. What's the point of `a:active`?

Comment: @Pacerier a link is "active" while you're clicking on it.

Comment: @hobbs, Yes that's its mechanism, but what's the point of it?

Comment: @Pacerier someone at Netscape thought it would be cool to make links respond to clicking by turning red. CSS is just making the old behavior expressible.

Answer (score 21):

It is used to differentiate between simple anchors and anchors with href attributes. [See demo jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eFS7L/).

```
<style>
a { color: red; }
a:link { color: blue; }
</style>
<a name="anchor">No href</a><br />
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">With href</a>
```

EDIT:
For this reason, it is important to cover all cases in your CSS. Option 2 is the only option that completely covers all cases. If you do not have anchor elements without `href` attributes, you are safe with option 1.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I do not wish to differentiate between those.

Comment: I don't get the -1. This is a good point and was not obvious from how usr asked the question (at least not before the edit)

Comment: @Layne it is not what I asked, even in the unedited question. This is not about what the variants *do*. I know that because I can read about it on the web. I want to know what I *should* do, not what I *can* do.

Comment: Rereading the edited question, I see what your intent is. It's completely subjective and depends on your html. If you don't have any simple anchors without href, then option 1 is sufficient. In my opinion, option 2 is best.

Comment: @usr to be honest you did. 1. your title. 2. Why not go for the simplest variant which is 1? 3. I cannot find a good reason to ever apply :link ... 4. "This question is not about what the variants do - all do the same thing." This answer shows that they don't to the same thing so yeah this is a good point why you might want to use :link, just because you don't care for this case doesn't mean that his answer is wrong because your question never stated that you don't care for this.

Comment: I said "all you need is one style for normal links and one for hover". I do recognize that the question did not emphasize that enough, though. Sad, that the question did derail so much. I guess the fact that nobody found a reason not to remove :link is answer enough.

Comment: @usr asks *Why do we need “a:link”? Why not just “a”?"*, the answer is because they do different things. This answer points that out, as does a ton of other answers. If this guy marks any of these as correct i'll die of shock. He'll delete this answer before that happens. I know his type ;)

Answer (score 2):

`a:link` is specifically for links that have not been visited. a applies to all `<a>` elements.as you said

> I don't care whether the link is visited or not

then you may avoid the use of `a:link` ...use of only `a...a:hover...a:active` will satisfy your need

and also `a:link` wont work if there is no `href` in your anchor but `a` will do

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use

```
<a>
```

to create a button so that could produce alternate results...
I always use `a:link`

Comment: Variant 2 uses `a` *and* `a:link`. Is that bad?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, but then I am not a 'clean code nazi'. For me, if it works but there is a quicker way to make it work, use the quick way. Therefore I would use /* 1 */

Comment: just my thinking! Now I want to know whether 1 is truly the *best* way. Maybe it is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

It solely depends on your intention, so for your example, I would simply style all anchor elements one color and only change the style when the element is hovered.

```
a {color: #000;}
a:hover {color: #f00;}
```

In your case, you are only changing the color of the link when it's hovered. You need to add the hover pseudo element after the base rule otherwise it would be overridden due to the cascading of the style sheet.

If you were to use all of the psuedo elements in this case and you wanted the only difference to be the hover it would look like this:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:focus, a:active {color: #000;}
a:hover {color: #f00;}
```

The pseudo-class names are self explanatory:

- :link - any unvisited link
- :visited - any visited link
- :active - when the link is active, e.g. when it's clicked or activated with a keyboard event
- :focus - when the link gains focus, e.g. when a user tabs through the elements and it is the selected element
- :hover - when it's hovered or moused over

The benefit of using a pseudo-class is that it will have a higher specificity than just targeting the anchor element. However, in your case it may not be needed.

Comment: @Derick, This wouldn't work for `a:active`. `a:active` must be declared after `a:hover` to work assuming your user uses a mouse.

Comment: @Pacerier - That's true.

Comment: If you wanted the color of the link to change when it was active, that's correct. For what I stated, "If you were to use all of the psuedo elements in this case and you wanted the only difference to be the hover it would look like this", the code is correct. I would advocate for adding a different color for active and adding it later in the cascade though.